# MPMoviePlayerController goes into black screen

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using the `MPMoviePlayerController` to play the video files in my application, videos are playing nice. But suddenly I opened one file and the `MPMoviePlayerController` opens in complete black screen, no controls are there. But I can see that there is a problem in my file and I resolved it.

I wonder is there any event that will be sent like `MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification` for these black screen issue. I tried with `MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown` event which seems to be not correct and tried with many events.

Now I want to know , is there any event will be sent , when the `MPMoviePlayerController` trying to open a file which results in black screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentations are fairly descriptive, though I will assume a black screen is a loading error:

`MPMovieFinishReason` Constants describing the reason that playback ended.

```
enum 
{
    MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded,
    MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError,
    MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited
};
typedef NSInteger MPMovieFinishReason;
```

> Constants:
>
> MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded
>   The end of the movie was reached.
>   Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>   Declared in MPMoviePlayerController.h.
>
> MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError
>   There was an error during playback.
>   Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>   Declared in MPMoviePlayerController.h.
>
> MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited
>   The user stopped playback.
>   Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>   Declared in MPMoviePlayerController.h.

These are passed through the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` notification with the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey` key.

Comment: @Safecase, would you mind formatting the quote a bit better for me?  Im on an iphone right now, which makes formatting impossible.  I'll accept your edit.

Comment: Thank you so much , No I am able to see the error using the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  and MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey

Comment: Yes. I never thought that we can get the error using the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey. So now , I am getting the error and removing the MPMoviePlayer from the superview.